# Echoing JSON Data in php

Tags: php, json

Im trying to echo some JSON Data. The problem is the data contains variables but my code isn't putting the variables into the string.
Heres my code:

```
$status = $row['Status'];
$priority = $row['Priority'];
echo '{"status":"$status","priority":"$priority"}' ;
```

this php is echoing

```
{"status":"$status","priority":"$priority"}
```

when I need to echo

```
{"status":"Completed","priority":"High"}
```

for example. How can I fix this?

Comment: You should not build json manually, use `json_encode()` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function

```
echo json_encode($row);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
json_encode($row)
```

Will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that PHP does not substitute variables in single quotes, only in double quotes (see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

For example:

```
$test = "a";
echo 'This is $test test and'.chr(10); 
echo "this is $test test.".chr(10); 

/*
   Creates the following output:
   This is $test test and
   this is a test.
*/
```

Note: `chr(10)` creates the new line.

And the solution to your problem is to use `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` as other people have suggested already.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your single quotes, PHP get all vars inside as strings, so break the string as follow:

```
echo '{"status":"'.$status.'","priority":"'.$priority.'"}' ;
```

On top of that, you can use `json_encode()` in order not to build your JSON object manually.