# Adding dataType: "json" in Ajax won't work

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to retrieve data from my database then display it into a modal, however, when I add the dataType:"json" in ajax, it seems like it no longer performs my php file.I am new to ajax and json so I don't really have an idea where I am having problem. BTW, I am trying to achieve a CRUD function that is why I am trying to load data into a modal for updating. I am using the same modal for create and update.

This is my html code.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addmodal">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h3>Add Product</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="" action="add.php" method="post" id="insert_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group input-width center-block">
                      <input class="form-control" type="file" name="img" id="img" value="" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group input-width center-block">
                      <label>Product Name:</label>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="pnametb" id="pnametb" placeholder="Product Name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group input-width center-block">
                      <label>Price:</label>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="pricetb" id="pricetb" placeholder="Price" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group input-width center-block">
                      <label>Category:</label>
                      <select style="" class="action form-control" name="category" id="category" required>
                      <option value="" disabled selected>Select a category:</option>
                      <?php
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                                {
                                ?>
                                <!-- Separated HTML and PHP -->
                                <option value="<?php echo $row['category']?>"><?php echo $row['category']?></option>
                                <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group input-width center-block">
                      <label>Description:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group input-width center-block">
                      <textarea style="color:black" name="destb" id="destb" class="message-box" placeholder="Description" rows="5" id="comment" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">
                    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="add" value="Add" id="add">
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

My ajax code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
       var id = $(this).attr("id");
       alert(id);
       $.ajax({
            url:"fetch.php",
            method:"post",
            data:{id:id},
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data){
              $('#img').val(data.img);
              $('#pnametb').val(data.productname);
              $('#pricetb').val(data.price);
              $('#category').val(data.category);
              $('#destb').val(data.description);
              $('#id').val(data.id);
              $('#add').val("Edit");
              $('#addmodal').modal('show');
            }
       });
  });
```

And here is my php file.

```
<?php
  //fetch.php
  $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
   if(isset($_POST["id"]))
    {
       $query = "SELECT * FROM productsa WHERE id = '".$_POST["id"]."'";
       $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
       $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
       echo json_encode($row);
    }
?>
```

Tell me if I need to clarify more things, I'm not really good in expressing what I want to happen. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Because `$row` isn't a JSON string..

Comment: You need to encode your data from the database into json. Use `echo json_encode($row);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Echoing JSON Data in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183302/echoing-json-data-in-php)

Comment: @ImClarky my bad, I actually had `echo json_encode($row);` on my code, I accidentally removed it

Comment: Thanks @Devon i'll check that

Comment: add on your ajax `encode:true`, @cifer

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile are you perhaps referring to `header("Content-Type: application/json", true);` ? i'm sorry i'm not really familiar with what you said

Comment: @cifer `url:"fetch.php",
            method:"post",
            data:{id:id},
            dataType: "json",
            encode : true`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile still no go mate

Comment: what results are u getting? @cifer

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile unfortunately, when I click the edit button nothing happens, the modal doesn't show up, i tried adding an alert on success function to check if it performs my php script but no alert so I guess it did not

Comment: @cifer from the code u provided there's no class called edit

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile `echo "<td> <input style='width:55px' class='edit btn btn-warning' type='button' name='$row[id]' id='$row[id]' value='Edit'></input></td>";` i had a code like this on my data table where I show all my data, so everytime there is a data, it will include an edit button for it, the edit class is included there

Answer (score 0):

First add a JSON header to your PHP script like so:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
```

Next instead of echo $row you do:

```
 echo json_encode($row);
```

And after that you probably have to change your succes: function of your Ajax call to fix printing out the data, but i will leave that up to you :)

Further reading and a more detailed explanation here:
[jQuery $.ajax request of dataType json will not retrieve data from PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147522/jquery-ajax-request-of-datatype-json-will-not-retrieve-data-from-php-script)

Comment: My bad, my code actually had `echo json_encode($row);` , i'll try to add a header, i'll let you know if it solves the problem thanks :)